# Can T400 work with 1333 MHz RAM?

Tags: memory, thinkpad

I am interested in buying 2x4GB RAM from either http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820144686 or http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A8NX3CQ for my Lenovo T400.

Both products are 1333 MHz, while the official link for T400 recommend 1067MHz (See below). Will 1333 MHz RAM be incompatible with T400? Thanks!

From the official website of T400 (http://support.lenovo.com/en_NO/product-and-parts/detail.page?DocID=PD005598)

> 3-8500 Non-Parity (NP) Double Data Rate Three (DDR3) Technology
>
> Two SO-DIMM Slots
>
> The use of 1067 MHz SO DIMM memory is recommended for this system.
>
> 512 MB, 1 GB, 2GB, or 4GB memory
>
> Supports up to 4GB maximum memory
>
> Note: Only 64-bit operating systems support more than 3GB of system memory (RAM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1333MHz RAM is backwords compatible and will work with 1066MHz if the chipset doesn't allow it to run with the designed 1333MHz. So yes, it should work.

Comment: Thanks! Which one of the two products would you prefer: newegg's GeIL or Amazon's PARTS-QUICK?

Comment: I would use the one from Amazon, which mentions the T400. Looks like this RAM was tested.

Comment: On the other way around, will RAM with lower frequency not work with expected higher frequency?

Comment: no, you can't run 1066MHz RAM with 1333MHz, this won't work.

Comment: In general, CPU frequency is much higher than RAM frequency. So what determines the expected frequency of RAM that can work with a given computer?

Comment: The CPU and chipset have a maximum frequency at which they can work with.

Comment: maximum frequency on RAM?

Comment: this is limited by the CPU/chipset.